# Why am I getting "throw new PostTooLargeException;" error when trying to upload a 10MB file when I have a validation rule "size:1000"

Tags: php, laravel, file, validation

Whenever I try to upload a 10MB file, I get this error `"throw new PostTooLargeException;"` because my php.ini file doesn't allow for such big files to be uploaded, however, I am not sure why is my validation is not catching it. I have this rule:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'files' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|size:1000'
    ]);
```

Wouldn't that straight up not allow for an upload attempt and just redirect me back to the upload page?

Comment: Framework validation is after php validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the maximum size limit in `php.ini`

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size

; from
; post_max_size = 8M
; to
post_max_size = 11M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize

; from
; upload_max_filesize = 2M

; to
upload_max_filesize = 11M
```

And restart the PHP FPM service

Otherwise you can handle the thrown error in `App\Exceptions\Handler`

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {
        return response([
            'error' => 'Customize the error message here'
        ], 422);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

[422](https://http.cat/422) HTTP status code is

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: What I am trying to do is not increase the maximum size limit, but handle the error when a user tries to upload a big file.

Comment: You have to increase the maximum size so that the request reaches the Laravel validation rule where you can handle the error, otherwise, it's handled by PHP

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with a custom handler for the thrown exception

Answer (score 0):

Before run laravel core, php try upload this file, and has limit by php.ini

Just set in php.ini value more then 10 MB

I also want to add...incase you have multiple php.ini and you are not sure which one your app is using. You can verify by checking your php_info() output. I have once faced the travail of editing the wrong php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Web request was processed in a sequence by web-server(Nginx, Apache), then fpm where php.ini works here, at last by Laravel application level.

On each period of the process, the request while filted according relative configuration.

Only when the request satify current rules, it can  be passed to the next process.

Comment: Ok so how do I error handle this? Even if I set the maximum size in php.ini to 50MB, someone might try uploading a 60MB file and he will get the error.